# Site position and its rectangle area on grid view

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, communities-list

The full list of the Stack Exchange sites can be displayed as [a grid view](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid#):

> [image: grid]

How are the size and position of the site icon calculated in this view mode?